# Error in defining a custom analyzer in elasticsearch for query

Tags: php, ajax, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a custom analyzer for querying to my elasticsearch index. I am using PHP for the web interface. Here is my code in fetch_nptel.php file which fetches data from the index:

```
<?php
//fetch_nptel.php

session_start();

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $link='';
 $search = $_POST["query"];
 $query = $client->search([

    'settings' => [
      'analysis' => [
        'analyzer' => [
          'my_custom_analyzer' => [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'my_tokenizer',
            'char_filter' => [
              'html_strip'
            ],
            'filter' => [
              'lowercase',
              'asciifolding'
            ]
          ]
        ],
        'tokenizer' => [
          'my_tokenizer' => [
            'type' => 'edge_ngram',
            'min_gram' => 1,
            'max_gram' => 10,
            'token_chars' => [
              'letter',
              'digit'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],

    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'bool' => [
          'must' => [
            'multi_match' => [
              //"fuzziness" => "AUTO",
              'analyzer' => 'my_custom_analyzer',
              'fields' => ['title','link','description'],
              'query' => $search
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      'from' => 0,
      'size' => 100
    ]
  ]);

  if($query['hits']['total']>=1){
    $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
  }

}

if(isset($results))
{
 $output .= '
  <div>Data found:</div>
 ';
 foreach($results as $r)
 {
  if(isset($r["_source"]["link"])){
  $link = $r["_source"]["link"];  
  $output .='

    <div>'.$r["_source"]["title"].'</div>
    <div>'.$r["_source"]["description"].'</div>
    <div style="color:blue;"><a href="' . $link . '">'.$r["_source"]["link"].'</a></div>
  ';
  }
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

When running the file, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\UnexpectedValueException: "settings" is not a valid parameter. Allowed parameters are "_source", "_source_excludes", "_source_includes", "allow_no_indices", "allow_partial_search_results", "analyze_wildcard", "analyzer", "batched_reduce_size", "ccs_minimize_roundtrips", "default_operator", "df", "docvalue_fields", "error_trace", "expand_wildcards", "explain", "filter_path", "from", "human", "ignore_throttled", "ignore_unavailable", "lenient", "max_concurrent_shard_requests", "opaqueId", "pre_filter_shard_size", "preference", "pretty", "q", "request_cache", "rest_total_hits_as_int", "routing", "scroll", "search_type", "seq_no_primary_term", "size", "sort", "source", "stats", "stored_fields", "suggest_field", "suggest_mode", "suggest_size", "suggest_text", "terminate_after", "timeout", "track_scores", "track_total_hits", "typed_keys", "version" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sgp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Endpoints\AbstractEndpoint.php:235 Stack trace: #0 C in C:\xampp\htdocs\sgp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Endpoints\AbstractEndpoint.php on line 235
```

It seems I can not define my custom analyzer during querying. So, how can I design  custom analyzer for my query?
This is the mapping of index (nptel):

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "COURSE LAYOUT": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Category :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Course Status :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Course Type :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Duration :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "End Date :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Exam Date :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Level :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Professor": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Start Date :": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "University": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "link": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the error message clearly mentioning `settings` is not a valid param, do you have a JSON for your mapping? which we can use to debug this issue? I am not familiar with PHP but with the help of JSON we can debug it

Comment: I have added the mapping. I know that I can not define an analyzer in query this way. But, When I saw  search_analyzer reference in elasticsearch documentation, I did not see anything about defining custom analyzer for query. Only default analyzer were used.

Comment: `settings` and `mappings` are only allowed at [index creation time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html). At search time you typically only send queries.

Comment: So how can I define an analyzer for my query? I know how to do that for indexing.

Comment: @preetshah, you can just use existing analyzers which is already defined in your index, as part of your `search_analyzer`

Comment: @preetshah, could you please check my answer, I provide more details.

Comment: yes, I just used the existing tokenizer and it worked. thank you so much @OpsterElasticsearchNinja.

Comment: My laptop went in some critical os error and than in BSOD. So, I could not reply, I am sorry for that. I had to repair it.

Comment: @preetshah, thanks for the update, glad you were able to make it work, also it would be great if you can mark it answer :)

Comment: any time @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message coming due to the fact, that you are trying to create a custom-analyzer during query time, which is not allowed in elasticsearch.

custom analyzers are part of Elasticsearch index settings and can only be updated using the `_settings` endpoint as explained in [this official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis).

> You can only define new analyzers on closed indices.
>
> To add an analyzer, you must close the index, define the analyzer, and
>   reopen the index. For example, the following commands add the content
>   analyzer to myindex:

### Elasticsearch Example to update a index, with new analyzer:

```
POST /twitter/_close

PUT /twitter/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "content":{
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"whitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /twitter/_open
```